# Extracting various lines from file using ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a number of text files, need to extract the first instance of some single lines, some consecutive lines and some text between lines:

> Document 1
>
> Title of the document
>    (TOD)
>
> Release 3
>   Version 2
>
> Authors
>
> Thomas E. Thomas, John L. John,
>   Fred A. Fred, Sandra K. Sandra
>
> Company A Address
>
> More Authors
>
> Page 3

From this example I need "Title of the Document (TOD)", 3, 2, and all the text between Authors and Page 3, not inclusive. I'm slowly learning so I have some code snippets, but they don't go far enough. I can get a match but need the first instance, and the instance and next line:

```
File.open("sample.txt").each do |line|
    if line[/Document/]
        puts line
```

I've tried to get intervening text but it's not quite right:

```
File.open("sample.txt").each do |line|
while gets
  print if [/Authors/../Page/]
end
```

If you feel this is too much help to ask for I'd appreciate hints/pointers.

Comment: Couldn't you just output lines until you hit the "Page 3" line?

Comment: You need to use a state-based approach. Keep track of what 'state' you're in, and for each line use a `case` statement to decide what to look for and what to do with what you find, and to change the state variable to a new value (probably a symbol) when it sees something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than read the file line by line I think it would be easier to read in the whole thing then search through it with regex. Something like:

```
File.open("sample.txt","r") do |f|
  text = f.read

  # everything between Document and Authors
  m1 = text.match(/Document(.*)Authors/m)

  # everything between Authors and Page
  m2 = text.match(/Authors(.*)Page/m)
end
```

Comment: You'll want to use the `m` regex modifier for this (it makes `.` match newline characters). `w` is not a valid regex option in Ruby.